# ERROR Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.6

We are facing the issue in replication that we are not getting any error in Show slave status\G output rather facing the following issue in Error Log File

```
[ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
```

Data for some tables is not being populated from Master Server and Slave does not update it self from the master.

We are using windows 2008 R2 and on Master Version is 5.6.19 and on Slave it is 5.6.26

Things looked so far are as below:
1. Change the master heartbeat value but it didn't work
2.increased the slave_net_timeout, Increased max_allowed_packet on master   and slave
3.Rebuilding Slave
4.Slave user permissions are also correct
5.Ping and telnet from both server also works and  windows firewall is off

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: i am having same problem , but my master version is 5.5.32 and slave is 5.6..My OS is Linux.. Server -id for both mysql is different , slave user can connect to master , bin log events are being transfer , recieved at slave end , but no record getting populated in slave.Relay logs are also getting purge after a while. In show slave status , position for both is same and second behind master is 0. Show process list at slave end doesnt yield so much result.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your network connectivity from slave to master was lost due t some reason and after the 
Try the following:
STOP SLAVE;
START SLAVE;

Comment: it didn't help at all

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for some known causes of this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-lost-connection.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/communication-errors.html